# set directive element attributes through parent controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to configure my directive module through my app level controllers. **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqWvK2zO2r9OfCKHoiph)**

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="App">
  <foodz index="index"></foodz>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['foodz']).
  controller('App', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.index = 1;
  }]);
```

**foodz.js**

```
angular.module('foodz', []).
  controller('foodzController', ['$scope',function($scope){

    //Data is coming in through external API
    $scope.$on('foodzFetched', function(e,d) {
      $scope.foodz = d;
    });

    //Lets say data to looks like:
    //[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"smoothy"}]
  }]).
  directive('foodz', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        index: '@'
      },
      replace: true,
      controller: 'foodzController',
      templateUrl: 'foodzTemplate.html',
      link: function(scope, controller) {}
    };
});
```

**foodzTemplate.html**

```
<div ng-controller="foodzController">
  <span>
    {{foodz[index].name}}
  </span>
</div>
```

So in this example, I am trying to pass the `index` through my `app` level controller into an attribute of my directive element which also has its own controller.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing. Can you try to create a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make `scope:{index:'='}`

Look at [Directive Definition Object](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

I think you are receiving `index='index'` (as string) in your controller. Using `=` it will get the value from parent controller.

Comment: +1 Thank you this was just what I needed. I should have read docs closer haha.